# PHPでマークダウンをHTMLに変換して表示したい

Tags: php, markdown

お世話になります。
表題の通り、PHPでマークダウンをHTMLに変換して表示させたいと思い、下記の
「PHP Markdown」のMarkdownExtraを利用しています。
https://github.com/michelf/php-markdown

しかし、これだとマークダウン中に記載しているページタイトルや作者が反映されず、困っています。
とりあえず、作成したPHPのコードとマークダウンを記載しておきます。
何か方法があれば、教えていただけると幸いです。
もし上記のスクリプトでタイトル等を指定できない場合、ほかによいスクリプトがあれば、教えていただけると幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

### ソースコード

#### PHPコード

```
require_once("./MarkdownExtra.inc.php");
$content = \Michelf\MarkdownExtra::defaultTransform(file_get_contents("./test.md"));
```

#### test.md

```
% テストページ
% 陸


# テストページ
　これは、テスト用のページです。
```

#### test.md（別サンプル）

```
---
Title: テストページ
Author: 陸
---

# テストページ
　これは、テスト用のページです。
```

Comment: 具体的にどのような出力結果(=HTML)になることを期待しているのか、についても記述があると回答が付きやすいかもしれません。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

まず、質問文中にある Markdown でのページタイトルや作者の書き方は[オリジナルの Markdown](https://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) にも [CommonMark](https://commonmark.org/) にも無い、特定の Markdown 処理系独自の拡張記法です。おそらく Pandoc の [metadata block](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#metadata-blocks) や [YAML metadata block](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#extension-yaml_metadata_block) を先にご存じだったのでしょう。この記法は Markdown 全般的には標準的な書き方ではありません。メタデータではなく単なる文字列として処理されます。

michelf/php-markdown はこの拡張記法に対応していないので、対応しているものを使う必要があります。自分は使ったことがありませんが [cebe/markdown](https://github.com/cebe/markdown) や [daylerees/kurenai](https://github.com/daylerees/kurenai) だとできそうです。また、PHP から Pandoc を呼び出して処理させても良さそうです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。お教えいただいたスクリプトを両方試してみました。とりあえず、どちらもうまく動きそうです。本当はPandocを直接呼び出せればいいんですが、現在利用しているサーバーではルート権限がなく、インストールできないので、とりあえず、どちらかを利用しようと思います。ありがとうございました。